# property of open cover of compact set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Consider $\overline{B_{\delta}(\vec{x})}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (a closed ball of radius $\delta>0$) Using Heine-Borel I can create a finite subcover for every open cover call it $$O: = \bigcup_{i={1}}^{n} U_i$$

It seems to me that there is always a $1 \leq j\leq n$ such that for a fixed i, $U_{i}\cap U_{j}\neq \emptyset$ for $i\neq j$. If this is true then I can always order the union so that $U_{i+1}\cap U_{i}\neq \emptyset$. Can this be done?

Comment: Why does it seem that you can do that.  Let B be the interval $[0,100] $ and let {$U_i $} be the finite subcover where $U_i=$ $(i-1,i+1) $.  That does not have your property at all.

Comment: Oh, you mean for *some* i != j.  Not *all* i != j.  And you mean for *all* j there is such an i.  Yes, you can relabel  the way you say.  BUT you must prove your proposition first.

Comment: Yeah I did that. Was just making sure I wasn't making a leap of faith. Thanks.

Comment: I was taking i to include 0.  $U_1\cap U_3 =\emptyset $.  There is no $j$ so that $U_j\cap U_i\ne\emptyset $ for $i\ne j $. For any $j $ $U_j\cap U_{i\nej;j+1;j-1}=\emptyset $.

Comment: I reworded my question to make it more clear what I was asking. I'm fixing an $i$ and showing that there is a $1 \leq j \leq n$ such that $U_{i}\cap U_{j}\neq \emptyset, i \neq j$

Comment: This is a property of B being connected.  Ordering... oh, wait no, you can't.  Maybe.  One piece of the cover may be connected to several pieces that go off in "threads" and you can't get a single line.  Consider S1 being in the center and S2-4 on edges.     Consider the closed ball of radius 2 center on the origin of the 2d plane.  Let S2 - S5 be the open ball of radius 1/2 at the points (0,+-2) and (+-2,0) and S1 be an open set containing the rest.  Can't make a path going through each set 9nly once.

Comment: Suppose you have an open cover of 4 or more sets where there is one set $U_{magic}$ of the open cover that intersects all $U_i$ where $i\ne magic$ but for any two $i,j$ where $i \ne j$ and $i \ne \magic$ and $j\ne magic$ then $U_i$ and $U_j$.  Then you can not reorder so that $S_i$ and $S_{i+1}$ intersect as that would mean one of every possible pair must be $U_{magic}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get down to it, this is actually a  combinatoric graphing problem and an obviously false one.

Let's have an open cover consisting of $U_1, .... U_n$ and you have determined that for every $U_i$ there is at least one other $U_j$ where $U_i$ and $U_j$ intersect.

Now lets make a graph of vertices $x_i$ were $x_i$ represents the set $U_i$ and let's create an edge connecting $x_i$ to $x_j$ if $U_i$ intersects $U_j$.  In the resulting graph every vertex has at least one edge to another, and the graph is connected.

Now you are asking if it will *always* be possible to find a path going through each vertex exactly once.

The answer to that is obviously no.

Consider a simple trifold.  A single center point connected to three otherwise unconnected points.  A,B,C are each connected to X and those are the only connection.  You can't travel passing through each point once because to get from $j \in \{ A,B,C\}$ to $k \in \{A,B,C\}$ you must pass through X.   And to get from the from $k$ to $m \in \{A,B,C\}$, you must pass through X again.

So consider $B$ equals the unit Ball.  $X$ is the entire plane except for three distinct points on the interior of $B$.  Let $J$, $K$, $L$  be small open neighborhoods of those three points that are missing for $X$ so that $J$ and $K$ and $L$ are mutually distinct.

Then $B \subset J \cup K \cup L \cup X$ is an open cover.  $J\cap X \ne \emptyset$ and $K\cap X \ne \emptyset$ and $L\cap X \ne \emptyset$ and $X\cap J \ne \emptyset$.  But we can not reorder them as $U_1, U_2, U_3,U_4$ so that $U_1 \cap U_2 \ne \emptyset$ and $U_2 \cap U_3\ne \emptyset$ and $U_3 \cap U_4\ne \emptyset$ because $X$ would need to be the common set in each pair and there is no common set in each pair.

Comment: It looks like you are calling $U_{3}$ and $U_{1}$ the same set. Looks like something went wrong with the formatting.

Comment: No, they don't.  U2 is a square at (-2,-2), U3 a square at (-2,2) and U4 a square at (2,2).  U1 is the entire plane except three pin pricks.  It's impossible to list them ans S1,S2, S3, S4 pairwise "connected" because three of the four are only connected to the same set and your chain has every set being between at most two.  The connecting set most between two of the sets and the third is isolated and cant be in the chain.

Comment: This is a good explanation. Thanks. So in a sense there is perhaps a maximal union that I can do this procedure with. In your example $J\cup X \cup K$ is the largest chain of unions with the property we want but it isn't an open cover of B...

Comment: I think this fruitless.  The connectedness of B means we can't divide a subcover into two separate partitions. That's true for B but not compact sets in general. However we can't say anything at all about the pair wise intersections of the sets in the cover.

Answer (score 0):

A counterexample is an irreduciable cover of two overlapping open sets or of n open balls sharing a point.

Comment: I don't know what an "irreduciable cover" is and if n open balls share a point then the intersection is certainly not the empty set.

Comment: It is a cover with no proper subcover.